# How to convert any model into lego bricks using geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to convert many 3D models to lego bricks. The effect is the same as this plugin https://www.blendermarket.com/products/bricker?ref=232.

Expected:
[image]

Here is what I get:
[image]

There are at least 3 issues:

1. I don't want space between bricks.
2. I don't want overlapping between bricks.
3. I don't know how to set material based on the input geometry.

I dont know how to fix this.

I found two tutorials but the first one is not for 3.0 and I am having a hard time to understand the second:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sjsb98AdmaM&t=130s
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5caYrpkHik&t=233s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve that with this node setup:

[image]

> Note: I didn't make it "perfect", i just wanted to show how you can do
> it. If you change values like count, size or vertices, it wont't look
> that good anymore. But i am sure you know how to calculate these
> values, so that they would automatically fit.

Comment: noticed you're really good with geonodes :)) i should probably learn basics as well

Comment: Thank you!!!! really good....nooo...but i know the basics ;) but yes, you should learn!!! it is just amazing!!!!

Comment: okay then, I'll look into it after I finish my current project :))

Comment: It works! I am having a hard time in deleting the geometry inside of the monkey. Not sure if I should post a new question. New question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250796/how-to-delete-points-inside-of-a-mesh