# How to delete points inside of a mesh?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Context: [How to convert any model into lego bricks using geometry node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250723/how-to-convert-any-model-into-lego-bricks-using-geometry-node/250728#250728)

I want to creat lego-like points on the surface of a monkey, but there are too many points inside of the monkey. I don't know how to delete points inside of the monkey. This is a problem because my project invovles millions of points.

What I tried:

1. Join geometry between the true monkey and lego monkey.
2. Union between the true monkey and lego monkey.

I know there is a delete gemotry node but I don't know how to specify points inside of the geometry.

My file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/0bbqOWNO

[image]

Comment: please check an answer as correct (click on checkmark left to the answer) if it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my attempt to solve this problem. Here you will get exactly one layer, using shape from a *Remesh* modifier:

[image]

I have to split GN into parts because I haven't found merge by distance function in GN. So that, I had to use a *Weld* modifier.

The issue that the *Remesh* doesn't use static values for the block size, so that solution is not perfect.

[image]